# Issue with deletion of event during MSGraph Subscription

Tags: ios, office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-api, subscription

We are using MSGraph SDK and have recently started seeings an issue in Subscriptions. When a meeting is cancelled from Windows system - OS version Windows 10 Pro Outlook Version - MS Outlook 2016, Our subscription server does not receive any updates. It happens only when calendar event is Cancelled(even if send cancellation option is selected) and works fine when we Schedule/Edit calendar events. Also it works fine from Office365(Web Browser) and when exchange is configured by Mac OS.

Can you please suggest if there is some setting in Outlook app or is it a bug in Outlook 2016?

Thanks, Vikash Kumar

Comment: Did you mean that the you call the Microsoft Graph to cancel the meeting from Window 10 Pro Outlook and it failed? If yes, what kind of app were you developing? I suggest that you track the request to see the detailed error message.

Comment: It sounds like they use the Outlook 2016 client to cancel the meetings.

Comment: Yes , we are using Outlook 2016 client for create/update the meetings. And we have integrated MSGraph SDK to one of our iOS Application. It works fine with Create and Update but not with delete using Subscription.

Comment: When you say "subscription", are you referring to a web hook subscription?

Comment: @ Marc LaFleur , Yes